# Ranges overlap - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, fetch, range, overlap

Does anyone know how to find ranges that overlap, using MySQL? Essentially, as seen on table below (just for illustrating the problem as the actual table contains 1000+ ranges), I am trying to fetch all ranges that overlap inside of a table.

Thanks!

RANGES

```
| count | Begin      | End  |        Comment                |
|  1    | 1001       | 1095 | overlaps with ranges 2, 3     |                            
|  2    | 1005       | 1030 | overlaps with ranges 1, 3     |                
|  3    | 1017       | 1020 | overlaps with ranges 1, 2     |                  
|  4    | 1110       | 1125 | no overlap                    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a `self join` and aggregation:

```
select r1.count, r1.begin, r1.end,
       group_concat(r2.count order by r2.count) as overlaps
from ranges r1 left join
     ranges r2
     on r1.end >= r2.begin and
        r1.begin <= r2.end and
        r1.count <> r2.count
group by r1.count, r1.begin, r1.end;
```

On a table with 1000 rows, this will not be fast, but it should be doable.  You may want to validate the logic on a smaller table.

This assumes that `count` is really a unique identifier for each row.

Note that `count` and `end` are poor choices for column names because they are SQL keywords.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04142931959aab47ea55fb1f24fbec14) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Bizarrely, COUNT isn't actually regarded as keyword (and neither COUNT nor END are 'reserved'), but I agree with the principle.

Comment: Thank for the help! Did tried as per fiddle, but I believe there is a conflict due to my version being perhaps a bit old (mysql 5.7) - I keep getting "statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TABLE ... SELECT"; not sure how to proceed from here as I am a newbie in SQL

Comment: @WilliamBracamonteBaran . . . This works in older versions as well:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=04142931959aab47ea55fb1f24fbec14.